# UPDATE rows with no match in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, exists

I have two tables:

```
TABLE A
  id  |  user_id  | name
------+-----------+-------
  1   |   122     | 'Bill'
  2   |   123     | 'Jim'
  3   |   124     | 'Sally'
```

```
TABLE B
  id  |  user_id  | title
------+-----------+-------
  1   |   122     | 'Boss'
  2   |   999     | 'Manager'
  3   |   124     | 'Worker'
```

I want to update all of A with `name = 'foo'` where there is no matching `user_id` in table B. Do not update the row if `user_id` exists in table B.

So in this case it would only update `Jim` to the name 'foo'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With Rails:**

```
user_ids_in_table_b = MobelB.pluck(:user_id)

ModelA.where.not(user_id: user_ids_in_table_b).update_all(name: 'foo')
```

You need to change the MobelA & MobelB models name to your models name in your app.

**In pure SQL:**

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET name = 'foo' 
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM table_b);
```

Comment: For sure. But it needs to be done is postgresql and not in a migration since the database is so huge. Is there a way to do this in postgres only?

Comment: +1 for the SQL solution, -1 for the Rails code (it's correct but horribly inefficient, and still leaks SQL into Ruby, so it's not even an "abstraction") = 0 overall.

Comment: What would be the Rails code for this situation in your opinion, @justsomebody ?

Comment: The SQL update wont work if any `user_id` in `table_b` is `null`.

Comment: that would be a gross violation of normalization principles, so i haven't considered that.

Comment: @MrYoshiji first, i would suggest against using ActiveRecord at all.  it's prone to generate inefficient SQL (the `1+N` problem is in practice usually `M+M*N`), and fails as an abstraction (`.where`, etc).  using it for sweeping updates leads to database operations running minutes instead of seconds, hours instead of minutes, or even days instead of hours (depends on the amount of data processed).  so, Rails is out for "migrations".  for application code, it would be `ViewAminusB.update_all name: 'foo'` accompanied by appropriate `RULE`s in the database.

Comment: what would happen if the field in the `SELECT` statement is not unique? That could make the query `SELECT...` return the same value in multiple rows. Will that break the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @chris It's `UPDATE`, not `SELECT`. But the principle is the same: each `WHERE` condition is (logically) evaluated for every (otherwise qualifying) row. No matter whether there might be other rows with the same value. What matters is that `NOT IN` **behaves surprisingly** with any `NULL` values involved. That's why it's typically (much) **slower** than `NOT EXISTS` and also why it's [**discouraged** for most use cases](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN) (incl. this one).

Answer (score 9):

[**`NOT EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) should be simplest, safest & fastest:

```
UPDATE tbl_a a
SET    name = 'foo' 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl_b b WHERE b.user_id = a.user_id);
```

This also works as expected with `NULL` values. As opposed to `NOT IN`. See:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN

Comment: hello Erwin, is this simpler, safer and faster than these? `WITH diff AS (SELECT user_id FROM tbl_a EXCEPT SELECT user_id FROM tbl_b), updates AS tbl_a NATURAL JOIN diff UPDATE updates SET name = 'foo';`  honest question, i know you are knowledgeable about it.

Comment: Erwin's versions is really much faster. say, 8 seconds over about 5 minutes on my several million records tables